# How to add validation to TableViewer?

Tags: java, validation, swt, jface, tableviewer

I want to add some validation to the different cells in the JFace `TableViewer`.

What is the best way to do it ?

I tried to use `Converter` and `Validator` for example

```
 // define a validator to check that only numbers are entered
 IValidator validator = new IValidator() {
     @Override
     public IStatus validate(Object value) {
         if (value instanceof Integer) {
             if (value.toString().matches(".*\\d.*")) {
                 return ValidationStatus.ok();
             }
         } 
         return ValidationStatus.error(value.toString() +"is not a number");
     }
};

// create UpdateValueStrategy and assign
// to the binding
UpdateValueStrategy strategy = new UpdateValueStrategy();
strategy.setBeforeSetValidator(validator);

Binding bindValue = ctx.bindValue(widgetValue, modelValue, strategy, null);
```

Does it the right way to do it for cells in `TableViewer`? (for example check `String`, `int`, `Date`s )

Comment: Is something wrong with the code you have written so far?

Comment: no I just want to know if it is the way to insert validation